# auto Complete doesn't work for me

Tags: codenameone

Is there an alternative to autocomplete TextField in codenameOne ? because it doesn't work for me.

i just create it one and add completion strings via GUI. and it doesn't show nothing when trying to type characters into it. this sounds very basic to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are examples of coding on [this page](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/AutoCompleteTextField.html).

```
Form hi = new Form("Auto Complete", new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
AutoCompleteTextField ac = new AutoCompleteTextField("Short", "Shock", "Sholder", "Shrek");
ac.setMinimumElementsShownInPopup(5);
hi.add(ac);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Does this work for you ? It doesn't give any auto completion list for me

Comment: i have my autocomplete texfields in a tab container. apparently it should be necessarily added to a form not a container !

Comment: It is not mine. I cited as an example from the site.

Comment: Well thank you any way sir ! i ve seen that code. but my issue was that i used auto complete cmpnt on a container not a Form.